# TOR, hangs at startup "Starting with guard context "default"\n'"

Tags: macos, tor

I had my tor command line installed, configured and running for months on my Mac.
Suddenly it stopped working, it starts and then hangs at

`Starting with guard context "default"`

Even the log file doesn't say much

```
Apr 18 08:39:44.836 [notice] Opened Control listener on 127.0.0.1:10041
Apr 18 08:39:44.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.4.2.7/share/tor/geoip.
Apr 18 08:39:44.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.4.2.7/share/tor/geoip6.
Apr 18 08:39:45.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Apr 18 08:39:45.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
```

Any clue?

Comment: to be sure it was not a problem on my ISP, i created an ubuntu machine on my laptop, installed tor and it worked fine. i m really clueless now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem. I installed another version of tor and the problem persisted. I concluded that both versions were accessing the same resource. The first thing that came to mind was `~/.tor`. Renamed it appropriately just in case I needed it further down the line and started tor. It worked. If there is no need to keep `~/.tor`, simply use:

```
rm -rf ~/.tor
```